# Расположение элементов в Layout из java Android

Tags: java, android

Нужно, чтобы добавить элементы один под другой из java кода, не используя xml - разметку. Есть код:

```
 //RelativeLayout - mainLayout
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.shopLayout);
        //RelativeGroup
        RelativeLayout groupOfItems = new RelativeLayout(ShopActivity.this);
        //Param for group
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams groupParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        groupParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
        //Element of all construction
        LinearLayout shopLinear = new LinearLayout(ShopActivity.this);
        //Item for redacting
        EditText note = new EditText(ShopActivity.this);
        EditText price = new EditText(ShopActivity.this);
        //Params for note
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams noteParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        noteParam.weight=3;
        //Param for price
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams priceParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        priceParam.weight = 1;
        //Param for shopLinear
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams shopLayParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //Configuration
        //Conf shopLinear
        shopLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        shopLinear.setLayoutParams(shopLayParam);
        //Conf note
        note.setLayoutParams(noteParam);
        //Conf price
        price.setLayoutParams(priceParam);
        //Adding
        //Add to shopLinear
        shopLinear.addView(note);
        shopLinear.addView(price);
        //
        groupOfItems.setLayoutParams(groupParam);
        groupOfItems.addView(shopLinear);
        //Add to main
        mainLayout.addView(groupOfItems);
```

Есть такой код, он делает группу RelativeLayout и туда кладет два Едит Текст , так вот , когда я пишу еще один такой же(с другими названиями переменных), то оно не добавляет его под предыдущий,а либо вообще не добавляет, либо добавляет прямо на место этого(скорее всего)

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Какой элемент под кем? Вы хоть капельку уважения окажите нам и расскажите христа ради чем мы вам сможем помочь ))

Comment: Короче, я сделал группу из RelativeLayout и  туда положидл два ЕдитТекст туда с параметрами. Есть главный RelativeLayout туда я добавляю эту группу. Вот, теперь я хочу добвит еще одну такую же в этот главный лэйаут, но оно не добавляет его под предыдущий а добавляет на место, хотя я писал groupParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);

Comment: Писал комментарии, ибо уже сам начинал путаться в своем коде

Comment: Привидите код, в котором *"когда я пишу еще один такой же"* и как все это вместе используется, чтобы был воспроизводимый пример проблемы. Как, по вашему, кто то должен догадаться, что и как вы там делаете неправильно и в чем проблема, экстрасенсорные способности у местных обитателей развиты очень слабо.

Comment: Для размещения элементов друг под другом проще использовать вертикальный `LinearLayout`.